# android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have set drawables to PageTitle for ActionBar Tabs. I want to display Icons on the Tabs instead of Text how should I go about it?

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return (CharSequence) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.geo_fence_96px);
    case 1:
        return (CharSequence) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.groups_96px);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then I call the SectionsPagerAdapter to set Image to Tabs in my MainActivity

```
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setIcon((Drawable) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
```

Comment: I want to display only icons on the Tabs how should I go about it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's about:

```
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
       .setIcon(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.geo_fence_96px)
       .setText("");
```